# Gradle task can be defined in root but not in child

Tags: gradle, synchronization

I have a gradle sync task:

```
task updateSharedCode {
    group = 'build'
}
updateSharedCode << {
    sync {
        from '../employee_shared/src'
        into 'src/shared'
    }
}
```

If I paste this task in the root's subprojects object everything runs fine But I only want to run this on a small subsection of my subprojects. But when I copy this task into one of the subprojects and remove it from the root I get the error

> Execution failed for task ':employee_app:updateSharedCode'.
>
> > Could not find method from() for arguments [../employee_shared/src] on project ':employee_app'.

I have no clue why this is happening so any help would be helpfull.

Comment: can you declare your task as updateSharedCode(type: Sync) and use from/into inside task closure?

Comment: That does work. Would you happen to know why my current implementation doesn't?

Comment: I found some discussions in gradle forums about broken sync closure. They say it is not a part of public api and can be broken. Using sync task instead of a closure is more stable I guess